# Excel Custom Function return WebImage not showing

Tags: excel, excel-addins, office-scripts, scriptlab

I am trying [Excel.WebImageCellValue interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.webimagecellvalue?view=excel-js-preview) in Excel Script Lab.

Here is my test code

```
/**
 * show image
 * @customfunction
 * @param {string} imagePath
 * @returns show image
 */
function meekouImage(imagePath) {
  return {
    type: "WebImage",
    address: imagePath
  };
}
```

But, it give different result for different image url.

If I test with `=SCRIPTLAB.MEEKOUCDF.MEEKOUIMAGE("https://www.mrexcel.com/img/excel-tips/2021/11/create-a-personal-macro-workbook-sm.jpg")`, it shows image correct in Excel Web.

If I test with `=SCRIPTLAB.MEEKOUCDF.MEEKOUIMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/hruDZ.jpg")`, it will show empty in Excel cell.

Is there any limit for online url for `WebImage`?

Comment: Our org used to block images from **i.stack.imgur** ... I'm going to assume you haven't actually tested that link to see if you can access the image (to be honest though, I'm sure you have) so I need to ask.

Comment: @Skin I can access this image from web browser